# Why do I need invoke toList() when I launch flatMap in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I can get a correct result when I use `my.flatMap {it.toList()}`.

I think that the val `my` is a `List<String>`, so I needn't to invoke `toList()`, but the code `var ok3=my.flatMap { it }` can't be compiled, why?

And more, the code `var ok2=my.flatMap { bb }` get an error result, why?

**Code A**

```
var my=listOf("abc","cef")
var bb=my.toList()

var ok1=my.flatMap {it.toList()}
var ok2=my.flatMap { bb }
//var ok3=my.flatMap { it }  //It's wrong
```

**Result**

[image]

**To Naetmul:**

Thanks!

Why do you think that `it` is `String` type in the code `val ok3=my.flatMap { it }`

In my mind, `it` should be `my` type in the lambda expression, and `my` is `List<String>` type.

**Image**
[image]

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sidenote: If you do not re-assign, `val` is more preferred than `var`.

---

```
val my = listOf("abc","cef")
val bb = my.toList()
```

Here, the type of `my` is `List<String>`, and its elements are `"abc"` and `"cef"`.

The type of `bb` is `List<String>` because `List` is transformed into `List`,
and its elements are `"abc"` and `"cef"`.

i.e., `my` and `bb` are equivalent, although they are different instances. You do not need `bb`.

---

```
var ok1 = my.flatMap {it.toList()}
```

This is similar to

```
var ok1 = listOf<Char>() // empty List
for (it in my) {
    // `it` is the `String` type.
    // For the 1st iteration, it = "abc"
    // For the 2nd iteration, it = "cef"

    val chars: List<Char> = it.toList() // String is transformed into List of Chars

    ok1 = ok1 + chars
}
```

---

```
var ok2 = my.flatMap { bb }
```

This is similar to

```
var ok2 = listOf<String>() // empty List
for (it in my) {
    // `it` is the `String` type.
    // For the 1st iteration, it = "abc"
    // For the 2nd iteration, it = "cef"

    ok2 = ok1 + bb // You know, bb = listOf("abc, "cef")
}
```

So, `ok2 = bb + bb` (the for-loop is iterated twice because `my` has 2 elements.)
which means `ok2 = listOf("abc", "cef") + listOf("abc", "cef")`
which means `ok2 = listOf("abc", "cef", "abc", "cef")`

---

```
val ok3=my.flatMap { it }  //It's wrong
```

This is similar to

```
var ok3 = listOf<?>() // empty List
for (it in my) {
    // `it` is the `String` type.
    // For the 1st iteration, it = "abc"
    // For the 2nd iteration, it = "cef"

    ok3 = ok3 + it
}
```

`ok3` must be the `List` type. However, `it` is `String` type, the type does not match.
So, compile error!

---

If you need to concatenate a `List` of `String`, you can use `joinToString()` method.

```
val my = listOf("abc", "cef")
val concat = my.joinToString("") // insert empty string between elements.
```

---

Refer to the [Kotlin standard library document of `List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html).

> ```
> fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.flatMap(
>     transform: (T) -> Iterable<R>
> ): List<R>
> ```
>
> Returns a single list of all elements yielded from results of
>   transform function being invoked on each element of original
>   collection.

Assume a variable `list` has the type `List<T>`.

If we want to execute `val newList = list.flatMap(function)`, then

`function` should have the function type `(T) -> Iterable<R>`.
(`function`'s parameter is `T`-type, and it retuns `Iterable<R>`. `List` is a subtype of `Collection`, and `Collection is a subtype of`Iterable`, so`List`is a subtype of`Iterable`.)

`newList` will have the type `List<R>`.

`it` in the question will be the parameter of `function`.

So, `it` will be `T`-type, not `List<T>`-type.
i.e., `it` will be `String`-type, not `List<String>`-type.

Comment: Thank! Would you please see my added content in the question ?

Comment: @HelloCW Updated. What `flatMap` does is: For each element in the list, apply the function (which returns a list or a collection), and then concatenate the return value (list or collection) of the function.

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
var my=listOf("abc","cef")
var ok1=my.flatMap {it.toList()}
//var ok3=my.flatMap { it }  //It's wrong
```

In this case :
- `flatMap` transforms `A` to `Iterable<>` 
- type of `it` is `String` . 
- `String.toList()` returns `List<Char>`

`var ok3=my.flatMap { it }` is wrong because you need to transform `String` to `Iterable<>` like `List<>`

2.

```
var ok2=my.flatMap { bb } get an error result
```

`my` has 2 elements, so `my.flatMap { bb }` do twice about return `bb` . 
 
you will get `{"abc","cef","abc","cef"}` after returning twice `bb`